# Динамическая группировка данных в CollectionViewSource

Tags: c#, wpf

В коде XAML в ресурсах прописан CollectionViewSource

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="viewCollection"  Source="{Binding Path=MyCollecthion,Mode=OneWay}">
            <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
                <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="MyEnum"/>
            </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
        </CollectionViewSource>
```

Как сделать так, чтоб при изменении свойства MyEnum автоматически элемент перемещался в соответствующую группу

Свойство MyCollection вернет ObservebleCollecthion<MyType>

Свойство MyEnum класса MyType имеет одно из заранее известных значений.

Comment: Поправь пожалуйста viewCollect***h***ion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Тебе нужен доступ к CollectionViewSource через ключ в самом коде формы - это так

`viewCollection=(CollectionViewSource)элемент_где_храниться_CVS.Resources["viewCollection"];`

2) Тебе нужно при изменении свойства вызвать следующее из этого объекта

```
    viewCollection.View.Refresh();
```

Comment: понятно, но не вариант, т.к. при 100+ элементов может происходить перегруппировка каждую секунду в итоге.
А это похоже очень затратно в итоге будет по производительности

Comment: что значит перегруппировка более 100 элементов и насколько оно затратно это еще один вопрос